# Target a single instance of multiple classes with Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm designing a caption module that shows/hides captions when clicked. I'd like to change the text of the button triggering the toggle, after the animation is complete.

The below works when one instance of button exists, but if there are more, the text does not change. <del>I don't have a solid grasp on moving through the DOM, how can I use `$(this)` to target the active button?</del>

Edit: For other beginners like myself, note this was a JS scope problem, not a DOM issue.

JS:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.caption').animate({ 
      height: 'toggle'
      }, 200, function() {
       // After animation is done:
       if($('.btn').text() == 'Hide'){
         $('.btn').text('Show');
       } else {
         $('.btn').text('Hide');
       }
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">  
    <ul class="slides">  
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="caption">
        <p class="txt"><span class="details">...</span></p> 
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <p class="txt">Hide</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would appreciate a quick explanation as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving a reference to the outer functions `$(this`):

```
 $('.btn').click(function(){ 

var self = $( this );

self.siblings('.caption').animate({ 

  height: 'toggle'

  }, 200, function() {

   // After animation is done:

   if(self.text() == 'Hide'){

     self.text('Show');

   } else {

     self.text('Hide');
   }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think that the lines marked below should have $(this) instead of $('.btn'):

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.caption').animate({ 
      height: 'toggle'
      }, 200, function() {
       // After animation is done:
       if($(this).text() == 'Hide'){ //<-- changed this line
         $(this).text('Show');       //<-- changed this line
       } else {
         $(this).text('Hide');       //<-- changed this line
       }
    }); 
});
```

The way you have it now, it is selecting all of the .btn items and that since there are multiples, it doesn't know which one to change.

Answer (score 0):

Function inside `animate` function lose the reference of the clicked `.btn` as this.

To remeber wich button is click, just save in a `var` before the `.animate()` the clicked target.

```
var btn = $(this)
```

You can then have acces to your button in the complete function with `btn`.